# Joining more than two tables laravel 5.3 using eloquent orm

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

**Request table:**

ID | Acrid | Type-id

**User table:**

ID | Acrid | Dptid

**Department table:**

ID  | Code

**Type table:**

ID | Name

`'Request'` table has one to one mapping with `'User'` & `'Type'`

This we can get using `Request::with(['user','type']);`

The user table has one to one mapping with the department table.

My question here is how to get the department details which is not related to the request table but related to the user table?

Answer (score 0):

You can write for multiple eager loading relation:

```
Request::with('user.type');
```

Comment: That I said in the que itself. I m asking how to get the department details which is not related to request but related to user

Comment: i see , you looking for nested relation you can do that and seperate every relation with dot like : user.country.city.state  @Orchid

Comment: For your particular problem, you can use `Request::with('user','user.department', 'type');`